# Can someone further explain the difference between 一緒に and 共に?

Tags: set-phrases

This is a follow up to the question “[What are the fundamental differences between the ～と一緒に and the ～とともに fragments?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/264/what-are-the-fundamental-differences-between-the-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E4%B8%80%E7%B7%92%E3%81%AB-and-the-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%AB-fragments)”  Someone suggested that I post my question as a separate thread.

Well, something is off for me. [It seems that Derek](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/315/769) and [rcjsuen's answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/310/769) clash somewhat. If I am being explicit or am emphasizing who I am doing an activity with, this implies that I and this person did everything together every step of the way. However, according Derek's answer, I would use 一緒に. But according to rcjsuen's reply, I would use 共に.

So what am I missing in this understanding?

Comment: Are you talking about Mark Hosang’s answer or rcjsuen’s answer?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto rcjsuen's. It's corrected now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  However, I am not sure how to answer your question.  In my opinion, Derek Schaab’s answer is correct and rcjsuen’s answer is incorrect, but different people have different opinions.

Comment: We rarely say「彼女とともに日本へ来た」in normal conversation... We rather use 一緒に when we talk. (ともに sounds a bit literary.) To me,「一緒に学ぼう、ともに頑張ろう」 doesn't sound very different from 「ともに学ぼう、ともに頑張ろう」「一緒に学ぼう、一緒に頑張ろう」or「ともに学ぼう、一緒に頑張ろう」(I'd use 「一緒に[勉強]{べんきょう}しよう。一緒に頑張ろう」 when I talk casually. When I write and want to sound literary, I'd use 「ともに学ぼう、ともに頑張ろう」「一緒に学ぼう、ともに頑張ろう」etc)

Answer (score 1):

Strange enough, in the case of the question thru your link [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/264/what-are-the-fundamental-differences-between-the-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E4%B8%80%E7%B7%92%E3%81%AB-and-the-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%AB-fragments), it seems that:

- 「誰々と一緒に」is basically equal to 'with someone', but
- 「誰々とともに」sounds a bit like 'someone followed me'.

In most of the cases they have zero differences. But sometimes we use 「誰々と共に」when we talk in a literary way, like「共に走ろう」.